# Python csv wordcount to column

Tags: python-3.x, csv, word-count

My apologies I have literally tried from scratch for four days. I am trying to take a csv and add a column with a wordcount to it. Each row would have its own count (specifically column 10). I have tried multiple ways, libraries, and pandas. I have also worked with family who know how to program and they seemed stumped. I will take any help I can get. The language is python.

```
import csv

with open('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Big data\\test.csv','r') as csvinput:
    with open('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Big data\\testa.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    row.append('Wordcount')
    all.append(row)

    words = []
    for i in words:
        words.append(i)

    words_counted = []
    for i in words:
        x = words.count(i)
        words_counted.append((i,x))

    for row in reader:
        row.append(row[10])
        all.append(row)
        words = row[0].split(" ")

    writer.writerows(all)
```

Comment: What's the format of `test.csv`?  One word per column, or one column containing some words?  Or multiple columns, each containing multiple words?

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a sample code how to do word count:

```
import pandas as pd
a =  "This is a sample line"
b = "lets count the words for each line"
df = pd.DataFrame([a,b], columns=['col'])
```

---

**df:**

```
col
0   This is a sample line
1   lets count the words for each line
```

---

```
df['totalwords'] = df['col'].str.split().str.len()
```

---

**df:**

```
    col                                 totalwords
0   This is a sample line               5
1   lets count the words for each line  7
```